# Django 1.5.5 displays original (en) strings always (does not translate)

Tags: django, configuration, django-templates, translation

I'm trying to implement simple Django 1.5.5 string translation in templates.

I have:

1. `USE_I18N = True` in `settings.py`
2. `'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'` in `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` in `settings.py`
3. `'django.core.context_processors.i18n'` in `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` in `settings.py`
4. Some `{% trans "My string" %}` strings in templates
5. `{% load i18n %}` in all templates
6. Ran `python manage.py makemessages -l he`
7. Translated my strings using Poedit
8. Ran `python manage.py compilemessages`
9. `LOCALE_PATHS = ('conf/locale',)` in `settings.py`
10. Restarted the server

Translated strings remain English.

I do check that current language is `he` using `{% get_current_language as LANG %}{{ LANG }}` in the template.

<strike>What did I do to deserve this</strike>Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I'm answering as a comment because I am not 100% sure that I've the solution, however it seems like a path issue ... Try doing something like this: ``PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) LOCALE_PATHS = ( os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, '../locale'), )
print LOCALE_PATHS``  -- to be totally sure that you've the correct path. Also don't forget that you have to have the path locale/he/LC_MESSAGES/django.mo (and po).

Comment: Bullseye! Make it an answer if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer (updated from comment):

It seems like a path issue (or else you'd see some error).

Try doing something like this in your settings:

```
import os
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) 

LOCALE_PATHS = ( os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, '../locale'), ) 
print LOCALE_PATHS
```

to be totally sure that you've the correct path.

Also don't forget that you need to have the path `locale/he/LC_MESSAGES/` that will contain your django.mo (and po) file.