# Localize django.contrib messages in Django

Tags: django, internationalization

In views:

```
    from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
    messages.success(request, (_("Thank you for contacting us.")))
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/')
```

In templates:

```
<div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}" data-alert="alert" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">
    <a class="close" href="#" onclick="$(this).parent().fadeOut('fast'); return false;">×</a>
    <p class="text-center" style="color: #0886B6; font-size: 20px;">{{ message }}</p>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

All the translated are translated despite the messages. I have create and compiled the message file but not working. What's wrong?

Comment: Please take look at my answer to this question for some hints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518783/django-1-5-5-displays-original-en-strings-always-does-not-translate/20519475#20519475

Comment: Like I said, sir I have already specified `locale_paths` in my settings.py and all of my translations working except the one I mentioned in the question. Thanks for the input though. Cheers

Comment: If you are testing locally, you need to restart the development server after compiling the messages (the localisations seem to be aggressively cached...)

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `ugettext_lazy with ugettext` worked.