# set_language not working in django internationalization

Tags: python, django

1. I included the following in the settings.py:

   ```
   LANGUAGES = (
       ('en', 'English'),
       ('ru', 'Russian'),
   )

   LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

   USE_I18N = True
   ```
2. marked the strings to be translated

   ```
   _('Enterprise')     # _ is lazy translate
   ```
3. included this in my URLCOnf:

   ```
   url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n'))
   ```
4. created the locale folder and did this:

   ```
   python manage.py makemessages -l ru
   ```
5. translated the strings and did this:

   ```
   python manage.py compilemessages
   ```
6. wrote this form:

   ```
   <form action="/i18n/setlang/" method="post">
           {% csrf_token %}
           <input name="next" type="hidden" value="/" />
           <select name="language">
              {% for lang in LANGUAGES %}
              <option value="{{ lang.0 }}">{{ lang.1 }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
           </select>
           <input type="submit" value="Translate" />
    </form>
   ```

I think I did all the steps to make it work but seems like I doing something wrong or missing something.

When use the form and try to translate and print `request.LANGUAGE_CODE`, it is showing me expected value. But the strings remain in the same language as they were

What is wrong here?

Comment: This smells like an incorrect path issue... Check my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20518783/django-1-5-5-displays-original-en-strings-always-does-not-translate

Comment: @Serafeim, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: No problem! you can also +1 my answer :)

Comment: @Serafeim I definitely will when I have enough reputation :)

Answer (score 6):

Probably you forgot to add the locale middleware into your settings file it should look like this

```
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware', 
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
```

You should take into consideration that the locale middleware should preced the commonmiddleware
And comes after the Sessionmiddleware 
As it takes it argument from the session middleware

Comment: Does `django.middleware.locale.u` exist? I had to add `'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware'`

Comment: My fault it should be as follows django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware

Answer (score 1):

You should define your `LOCALE_PATHS` in settings.py file like this

```
LOCALE_PATHS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'locale/'),
)
```

django doesn't by default look for locale dir in root of project.